# FileWriter won't write all of the file - yes, I have called close()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, filewriter

Here is the code:

```
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csv);
        for (String line: lines) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.write("\r\n");
            Log.d(TAG, line);
        }
        writer.close();
```

Each line gets shown perfectly in LogCat and no errors are thrown anywhere, but the actual file cuts off at the end of the second line.

Edit:

Turns out the problem was a known bug with Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282

I fixed the problem by adding the following line after writer.close:

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);

Comment: How are you checking the contents of the file? If you do this with very simple lines ("a", "b", "c") do you still observe the problem?

Comment: What do you mean checking the contents? As for trying with simple lines, yes that works OK.

Comment: I mean you're clearly looking at the file somehow (otherwise you wouldn't know that there's anything wrong) - how are you doing that? What exactly are you seeing, and how? If you can't reproduce this with very simple lines, have you worked out what the lines need to contain in order to cause the problem?

Comment: Oh I get you now. I'm checking the contents by reading it from my phone on my computer.

Comment: Try `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(csv), "UTF-8"))`. Maybe a charset issue.

Comment: Reading it *with what*? Notepad? Something else?

Comment: I'm reading it with Notepad. I tried it with other text and I noticed it cut off on that too at a certain number of characters. The file is stuck at 153 bytes. I tried changing to filename but that doesn't get created now. Doesn't throw any errors - just doesn't create it. The code is the same as when I made the original file.

Comment: Actually, when I check with the phone's file manager, the files all show up. They just don't show up on my computer. I'm using this path: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "filename.csv"

Comment: I just restarted the phone and everything came up properly on my PC. How do I make it so that the user doesn't have to restart their phone?

Comment: The problem has been solved. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was a known bug with Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282

I fixed the problem by adding the following line after writer.close:

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);

Comment: accept your own answer if it's the best one for the future readers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the content your are writing is still in the memory and not sync to disk.

Sometimes the FileSystem will waiting for more content to flush to disk together.